# Lua recursive function with variable arguments

Tags: lua

I am trying to write a string join function that will work with both tables and variable arguments as input. Here is what I have so far:

```lua
function join(separator, ...)
    local result = ""
    local vargs = {...}
    local n = #vargs
    for i = 1, n do
        local varg = vargs[i]
        if type(varg) == "table" then
            result = join(separator, result, table.unpack(varg))
        elseif varg ~= nil then
            result = result..tostring(varg)
            if i < n then
                result = result..separator
            end
        end
    end
    return result
end
```

However, when I try to use it with the following input:

```lua
print(join(",", "1", "2", "3"))
print(join(",", {"a", "b", "c"}))
```

The output is this:

```
1,2,3
,a,b,c
```

I did not expect the `,` at the beginning of `a,b,c`.

From what I understand, it seems somehow the separator is getting added to the variable arguments when calling the function inside the function (recursiveness). But why is that? And how can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend collecting your values into a table, then use `table.concat`. This is faster and also covers your issue.

Comment: In the recursive call, you pass `result` as the first `...` argument, so it will get a comma after it even if it's an empty string.

Comment: @luther wow I didn't see this. /facepalm thank you that was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
...
if type(varg) == "table" then
   varg = join(separator, table.unpack(varg))
end
if varg ~= nil then
   ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Well uh sorry if it's not really useful but maybe it's because you put the: , into "" that it print the ,